# Why can't I pass my user_name value into my component? (Auth)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

**I am trying to pass the name of the user after authentication into a Vue component, but I get a `name: undefined` value after load.**

> Here is my `AuthService.js`:

```
//config details taken from OAUTH JS doc: https://github.com/andreassolberg/jso

import { JSO, Fetcher } from 'jso';

const client = new JSO({
  providerID: '<my-provider>',
  default_lifetime: 1800,
  client_id: '<my-client-id>',
  redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:8080/',
  authorization:'<my-auth-server>/oauth/authorize'
  //scopes: { request: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'] }
});

export default {
  getProfile() {
    // JSO plugin provides a simple wrapper around the fetch API to handle headers
    let f = new Fetcher(client);
    let url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile';
    f.fetch(url, {})
      .then(data => {
        return data.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        return data.user_name;
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error('Error from fetcher', err);
      });
  }
};
```

> Then, in my single file component named `MainNav`, I have:

```
import AuthService from "@/AuthService";
export default {
  name: "MainNav",
  data() {
    return {
      name: ""
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.name = AuthService.getProfile();
  }
};
</script>
```

Anyone have any tips on how I can get the `user_name` value from the AuthService to my component? I will then need to then display the name in my nav template. Doing a console.log test works fine, just can't return it to my SFC. *Also, the JSO library is here: https://github.com/andreassolberg/jso#fetching-data-from-a-oauth-protected-endpoint*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `getProfile` returns nothing (undefined). I see you use es6 then you can use async functions

```
//config details taken from OAUTH JS doc: https://github.com/andreassolberg/jso

import { JSO, Fetcher } from 'jso';

const client = new JSO({
  providerID: '<my-provider>',
  default_lifetime: 1800,
  client_id: '<my-client-id>',
  redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:8080/',
  authorization:'<my-auth-server>/oauth/authorize'
  //scopes: { request: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'] }
});

export default {
  getProfile() {
  // JSO plugin provides a simple wrapper around the fetch API to handle headers
  let f = new Fetcher(client);
  let url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile';
  return f.fetch(url, {}) // return promise here
    .then(data => {
      return data.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
      return data.user_name;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error('Error from fetcher', err);
    });
  }
};
```

And

```
import AuthService from "@/AuthService";
export default {
  name: "MainNav",
  data() {
    return {
      name: ""
    };
  },
  async created() {
    try {
      this.name = await AuthService.getProfile();
    } catch(error) {
      // handle
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Or without async (add one more then)

```
import AuthService from "@/AuthService";
export default {
  name: "MainNav",
  data() {
    return {
      name: ""
    };
  },
  created() {
    AuthService.getProfile().then((userName) => this.name = userName))
      .catch((error) => { /* handle */ })
  }
};
</script>
```